# How do I make a textfield with Tags on Ext JS Grid?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, forms

How do I make a textfield with Tags on Ext JS Grid?

I want to make a textfield like example on below page:

jQuery TextExt Plugin http://textextjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a ux component called BoxSelect.

See [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134751-Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect-Intuitive-Multi-Select-ComboBox) and the related links within it.